# errors while unserialize data received from shell exec in php

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have the below line of code to create image thumbnail of different sizes in background using shell_exec. It was working fine online but on my xampp localhost i kept getting errors below in the log file.

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 182 bytes in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\example.com\assets\createImgeThumbnils.php on line 4
>   bool(false) PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 182 bytes
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\example.com\assets\createImgeThumbnils.php on line
>   4

Here is what i have in my upload script to send the shell command

```
<?php
$arg = array ( 
    "dirname" => "gallery/p", 
    "basename" => "878513f88f048477029c8836438773ef-1.jpeg", 
    "extension" => "jpeg", 
    "tag" => 1, 
    "filename" => "878513f88f048477029c8836438773ef-1"
);
$arg = serialize($arg);
shell_exec(
    "C:\xampp\php\php.exe 
    " . __DIR__ . "/../../../assets/createImgeThumbnils.php 
    '".$arg."' 'alert' >> 
    " . __DIR__ . "/../../../server_assets/alert_log/paging.log 2>&1
");
```

Here is my example script for `createImgeThumbnils.php`

```
<?php
if(isset($argv[1]) && !empty($argv[1])){
    $data = $argv[1];
    //$data = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $argv[1]);
    var_dump(unserialize($data));
}else{
    echo "NO is empty";
}
```

Below is the received data when i check `unserialize($argv)`

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(130) "C:\xampp\htdocs\example.com\app\test\file_path/../../../assets/createImgeThumbnils.php"
  [1]=>
  string(180) "'a:5:{s:7:dirname;s:9:gallery/p;s:8:basename;s:39:878513f88f048477029c8836438773ef-1.jpeg;s:9:extension;s:4:jpeg;s:3:tag;i:1;s:8:filename;s:34:878513f88f048477029c8836438773ef-1;}'"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "'alert'"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unserialize is complaining about the leading single quote. But your serialized string also misses all double quotes. Since it was working online, I think your shell on localhost treats quotes differently. You can avoid problems like that, if you encode your arguments with e.g. base64. In your first script:

```
shell_exec(
  "C:\xampp\php\php.exe 
  " . __DIR__ . "/../../../assets/createImgeThumbnils.php 
  ".base64_encode($arg)." 'alert' >> 
  " . __DIR__ . "/../../../server_assets/alert_log/paging.log 2>&1
");
```

and in your second script:

```
$data = base64_decode($argv[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but this this the best way to do this?

Comment: Base64 needs one third more space than not encoded data; so it's not the best/shortest way to pass the data. But you don't need to worry about special characters.